# Strings file Xcode - Remove the first and last " + ;

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa

I just started using strings file in my projects. Or well, i'm trying to.

I had an error for a few days, and finally figured out you actually have to make strings in the file with "" and end the lines with a ; - that was a bummer to figure out ;)

Anywhoo, now i'm trying to get it sorted out and separated into smaller strings. It's working like a charm, but i just can't seem to get rid of the "" and ; on each line of the string.

For instance, i have this in my strings file (i'm separating by comma):
"This is a string,This is another string,And a final one";

I am trying to get it into 3 different strings, and after having done it, it looks like this in my 3 strings objects:

"This is a string
This is another string
And a final one";

So i need to remove the " in string 1, and the " + ; in string 3.

I hope it made sense. I really can't seem to figure this one out, as i haven't really worked with sorting around in strings too much, and yet alone working with a strings file.

Thanks on advance.

Comment: You *are* using NSBundle's methods to get the strings, right? You don't have to parse strings files yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick if ALL strings have the " and "; at the beginning/end of the total string.

```
firstString = [firstString substringFromIndex:1];
lastString = [lastString substringToIndex:[lastString length] - 3];
```

If you want to remove all occurances of " and ; use this before splitting:

```
totalString = [totalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
totalString = [totalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@";" withString:@""];
```

Comment: awesome:) glad to have helped you

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you use a tool to generate the .strings file from your code.  You don't have to construct it manually.

In your code, when you want to use a string that should be localizable, you typically use one of the `NSLocalizableString...` macros.  Like so:

```
textField.stringValue = NSLocalizableString(@"Hello, World!", "Standard programming greeting");
```

To generate the Localizable.strings file, you use the [`genstrings`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/genstrings.1.html) tool to scan your code for uses of such macros (and a few other things).  It produces .strings files in the proper format.

For more, see these Apple documents:
[Resource Programming Guide: String Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html)
[Internationalization Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171-SW1)